# How to configure CXF servlet outside of web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cxf

I want to be able to disable webservices using spring profile. I have surrounded all the cxf related beans with:

```
<beans profile="webservices">...</beans>
```

But what is left is cxf servlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm thinking to replace it with:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>webservicesDispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>webservicesDispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I need to configure webservicesDispather to do the same thing as the CXFServlet does. So far contents of webservicesDispatcher-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="... > 
    <beans profile="webservices">    
     <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
         <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
         <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />    
    </beans>
</beans>
```

So, any idea what contents of webservicesDispatcher-servlet.xml should be?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK CXFServlet will have to be the front controller for CXF flow, DispatcherServlet cannot replace the functionality that CXFServlet performs - any reason why you want the DispatcherServlet alone to handle both Spring MVC flow and CXF WS flow - CXF servlet can refer to the beans in the context file defined by the DispatcherServlet either way.

Comment: I just want that cxf would not be initialized if webservices profile is disabled.

Comment: How about using a `WebApplicationInitializer` to programatically register the servlet  - based on a system property either register the CXFServlet or avoid registering it. You can activate your webservices profiles also using the same system property.